# how to indent html output using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using PHP to loop through an array and return results, each result is being displayed along with some html code. Right now, to achieve the indent I am using a DIV tag and setting the margin like so:

For output 1:

`<div style='height: 20px;margin-left: 60px;'>`

For output 2:

`<div style='height: 20px;margin-left: 110px;'>`

[image]

The issue with this method of setting the margin for each output is it relies on the criteria to always match but sometimes the criteria doesnt match and the indentation is ruined.

So basically is there another way using CSS or some other way to increase the indent for each output rather than having to specify a fixed one ?

Apologies if I am not being clear enough but hoping you can understand what I am asking, otherwise let me know and I will try clarify some more.

Here is a sample code:

```
foreach ($data[0] as $data) {
    if ($data == a) {
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 0px; '><img src='img/server_s.png' style='float: left;'></div>";
    } elseif ($data == b) {
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 60px;'><img src='img/link.png' style='clear: left;'></div>";
    } elseif ($data == c) {
        echo "<div style='margin-left: 110px;'><img src='img/link.png' style='clear: left;'></div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: give code example too what you have tried so far

Comment: done. refresh my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this work for you

```
$a=0;    
foreach ($data[0] as $data) {

          if ($data == a) {
    echo "<div style='margin-left: ".$a."px; '><img src='img/server_s.png' style='float: left;'></div>";
} elseif ($data == b) {
    echo "<div style='margin-left: ".$a."px;'><img src='img/link.png' style='clear: left;'></div>";
} elseif ($data == c) {
    echo "<div style='margin-left: ".$a."px;'><img src='img/link.png' style='clear: left;'></div>";
}


$a=$a+60;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I should point out that for each condition there may or may not be a match but I want to retain an orderly indentation.. your code looks interesting so I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Qaisar, this does work properly and exactly as needed. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it through simple list tags of HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
ul li {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 15px 0px;
}
span {
   border: 1px solid #000;
   padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>A Nested List</h2>

<ul>
  <li><span>Milk</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>Tea</span></li>
        <ul>
            <li><span>Black Tea</span></li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Reference URL for sample: http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested
Thanks & Regards,

**Vivek**